# C++ constructor implicit type conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Let's assume that I have this code:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int y) { cout << y; }
};

int main() {
    A a(1.5);

    return 0;
}
```

Even though 1.5 is a `float`, this code works and returns 1. The `float` was implicitly casted to `int`. Why didn't it throw an exception? Do constructors depend on amount of parameters or their types? Where can I read about this?

Comment: Where can I read about this? Try [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), and remember this is the easy to digest version! If you want the complete version see the C++ standard.

Comment: It would *never* throw an exception. Exceptions are run-time errors. If this weren't allowed by the language, it would be a compile-time error. There is no automated run-time parameter validation in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because such [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_conversions) (from `double` to `int`) is allowed.

> **Floating–integral conversions**
>
> - A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined (even when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply).

If you don't want such construction happens, you can add a constructor taking `double` and mark it as `delete`. E.g.

```
class A {
public:
    A(double) = delete;
    A(int y) { cout << y; }
};
```

BTW: `1.5` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you!